# How to use yarn's portal protocol?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg-v2

#### The problem

When I use **the portal protocol of yarn** to add my **local package** it just gets installed from the npm registry instead.

I want to develop said package so I need to be working with the latest code not the one published to the registry.

#### What I tried

I tried using `yarn add vexflow-repl@portal:../../vexflow-repl` by following the example provided by [yarn's official website](https://yarnpkg.com/protocol/portal).

Before I run the above command my dependencies look like this:

[image: dependencies before]

After I run the command they look like this:

[image: dependencies after]

Nothing else changed in my **package.json** and the package is installed from the **npm registry** instead of my local folder.

#### Observations

If I instead use `yarn add file:..\..\vexflow-repl` the package does get installed from my local folder and my dependencies look like this:

[image: dependencies after adding with file protocol]

With **yarn's file protocol** I can work as I intended with the latest code from my package at the expense of duplicate files and some overhead.

#### System information

I use windows.